# Excluding nested directories with grep

Tags: grep

I would like to exclude a nested directory from my grep searches, such as `/path/to/file`. For example:

```
jake@jake-laptop:~/test$ egrep -r --exclude-dir="path" "hello" .
jake@jake-laptop:~/test$ egrep -r --exclude-dir="to" "hello" .
jake@jake-laptop:~/test$ egrep -r --exclude-dir="file" "hello" .
jake@jake-laptop:~/test$ egrep -r --exclude-dir="path/to/file" "hello" .
./path/to/file/f.txt:hello
```

In the last line, the file is not excluded, apparently because I have multiple nested directories provided with the `exclude-dir` argument. How can I get the last example to exclude searches in the `path/to/file` directory?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `--exclude-dir` is only compared against the basename of the path, ie the current subdir. So path/to/file will never match dir "file", but only `--exclude-dir=file` will, or a glob version eg `--exclude-dir=*ile`.

The usual alternative is to use `find`, eg if it handles option `-path`:

```
find . -path ./path/to/file -prune -o -type f -exec egrep -l 'hello' {} +
```

The pattern after `-path` has to match the path including your starting dir, but you
can use globs to simplify, eg `'*path*file*'`, where * matches / as well.

Otherwise, you can resort to `find | sed | xargs egrep`.